# IMacros - Trouble with extracting div element from a table

Tags: javascript, html, imacros

I have recently been using IMacros to do some basic web navigation tests. I am currently looping a search query on one of our applications where I want to extract the final result (Total number of events captured) which is listed under the table as shown in the picture.

The bit I am failing to grasp is when I look at the element info, the div that contains the dynamic number doesn't have an ID. I have tried finding a solution but I can't see any examples similar to this. Row 15 in my IMacro is where my problem is, I end up with a CSV file with some columns populated with #EANF#

The Image shows the piece of data I am trying to extract along with its element info. Also pictured is my IMacro recording. Line 15 is where I'm going wrong:
[image: Example Image]

Comment: Elements without ids are not a problem for 'iMacros'. In the line #15 the command has a wrong syntax. Perhaps you need something like `TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:gwt-HTML EXTRACT=TXT` ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. That has got me closer! however I now get this output in CSV <div class="gwt-HTML">1-1 of over 0</div> when using HTM EXTRACT. If using TXT I get 1-1 of over 0. So it's the right area but not picking up the value.

Comment: I think that's a wrong area if you get incorect texts. Try to alter the number of the `POS` parameter (1, 2, 3 etc.) until you get what is needed.